# PHP reverse order from mysql

Tags: php

I have this piece of code:

```
return $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `messages` where `toid`='$userid' and `fromid`='$userConvensation' or `fromid`='$userid' and `toid`='$userConvensation' order by `id` DESC LIMIT 10");
```

It takes the 10 latest messages.

But i need the 10 latest messages, but also in reversed order. how am i able to do that?

output code:

```
foreach($messages->result() as $thisMessage) {
//dostuff
}
```

Comment: `("SELECT * FROM `messages` where `toid`='$userid' and `fromid`='$userConvensation' or `fromid`='$userid' and `toid`='$userConvensation' order by `id` DESC LIMIT 10") `AS latest ORDER BY id ASC`?

Comment: @aldrin27, why don't you put that into an answer ?

Answer (score 1):

how about subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM `messages` WHERE id IN (
  SELECT `id` FROM `messages` where `toid`='$userid' and
  `fromid`='$userConvensation' or `fromid`='$userid' and
  `toid`='$userConvensation' order by `id` DESC LIMIT 10
)
ORDER BY `id` ASC
```

Comment: for some reason now. its not selecting it by the toid and fromid, or only getting 10 rows .prntscr.com/8lqcxd

Comment: Error Number: 1235

This version of MariaDB doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your query and renamed it and reorder that.

```
("SELECT * FROM messages` where toid='$userid' and fromid='$userConvensation' or fromid='$userid' and toid='$userConvensation' 
 order by id DESC LIMIT 10") AS latest ORDER BY id ASC
```

Comment: for some reason now. its not selecting it by the toid and fromid.http://prntscr.com/8lqcxd